# iOS Safari: disable elastic scrolling also disables all scroll-able DIVs

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am using this javascript in my mobile-web application to prevent the elastic scroll in my page:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(e.target);

    }, false);
```

However, it disables the elastic scroll in my page but it also disables all the scrolls in my page. For example, I have a DIV having scroll: auto; which is also disabled with the above code.

I only need to disable the "bouncing elastic" in my page and not on the other elements I have in my applications.

How can I resolve it? I also tried the following CSS, but did not work:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```